# Can I launch an activity from boot-up and have it go into the background without the user seeing it, android

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

At the moment I have code that starts an application from boot-up but opens it into the foreground.
This was done by

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent start = new Intent(context, ApolloMobileActivity.class);  
        start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(start);
```

Then to get it sent to the background at boot-up I created another java file called, StartAtBootService
so I changed the receiver class to:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction("com.example.ssab.StartAtBootService");
  context.startService(i);
                    }
```

And the Service class was

```
 public class StartAtBootService extends Service 
 {
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService Created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService -- onStartCommand()");          

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /*
     * In Android 2.0 and later, onStart() is depreciated.  Use
     * onStartCommand() instead, or compile against API Level 5 and
     * use both.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService -- onStart()");         
        }
     */

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService Destroyed");
    }
 }
```

Is it possible to change the StartAtBootService to run an activity in another java file called ApolloMobileActivity in the background?
I have tested this code and even though it runs in the background at boot-up it doesn't run the code in ApolloMobileActivity.

Please help! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

> An Activity is an application component **that provides a screen** with
>   which users can **interact** in order to do something, such as dial the
>   phone, take a photo, send an email, or view a map. **Each activity is
>   given a window in which to draw its user interface**. The window
>   typically fills the screen, but may be smaller than the screen and
>   float on top of other windows.

*from [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)*

You can start an Activity, but there is no such thing as an invisible Activity. These are UI-components. If you want to do invisible work in the background, you have to do it in your service.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you clarify how to code it using service?

Comment: Basically just put everything you want to be done inside `onStartCommand()`, and when its done, use `Service.stopSelf()` to kill the service (for performance/battery reasons). Keep in mind that a service runs in the UI thread, so if you have to do heavy work (such as calculations, downloads,...) use `AsyncTasks` to move your work away from the UI thread.

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it was helpful. :)